# pylint(no-name-in-module) Не видит модуль whitnoise

Tags: python, linux, django, wsgi

No name 'DjangoWhiteNoise' in module 'whitenoise.django'pylint(no-name-in-module)

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'BagleyFinder.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Данная строчка подсвечивается красным from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise.
Весь код находиться в wsgi.py

Comment: Ответ хорошо был дан тут: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621436/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-wsgi-application-project-name-ws)

Comment: `pip install pylint-django` часто решает подобные вопросы

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но в файле wsgi.py надо было убрать 2 строчки